# Two VMs sniff traffic using Network Tap over LAN

Tags: linux, networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine, suricata

I have two VMs running in a VirtualBox. One is running Windows 7 and the other Kali Linux. The host computer is connected via LAN to a Raspberry Pi running a bridge interface so it can monitor the traffic using Suricata IDS. The setup is like so:

LAN <-> Raspberry Pi <-> PC (VM 1 and VM 2)

I want to monitor the traffic going to and from the two VMs via the Raspberry Pi. 
I have configured the two VMs to use bridge interfaces and I would thereby assume that their traffic will go through the LAN port on my PC and then to the raspberry. 
However this is not the case and no traffic to and from the two VMs are logged. Any ideas what I do wrong?

Comment: Are the private IP addresses in same subnet in RPi and VMs?

Comment: Yes, both RPi and VMs are in the same subnet.